# VueJS - How can I bind animate.css class in onclick method in vuejs?

Tags: vuejs2

When I click **a** button, it does not add or bind `animate.css` class in another div class.

Comment: can you provide a code example first?

Comment: I am extremly sorry. i can't provide it right now. if you give me an explanation of it that will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe that's what you meant, but your question does not contain details

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
   animate() {
    let elem = document.querySelector('.another-class')
      if (!elem.classList.contains('bounce')) {
  elem.classList.add('bounce')
      }
 setTimeout(() => { elem.classList.remove('bounce') }, 1000)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animate.css@3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.9/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <h1 class="another-class animated">Animate.css</h1>
    <button @click="animate">
    animate it
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: show me the error log and show the project architecture, please!